# Im using Angular and I need to time how long someone has been on a page

Tags: javascript, angular, timer

I have seen a few ways to do it using vanilla JS and jQuery but unfortunately non of them on how to figure this out using Angular.

I am not the most experienced but I am trying my best to get some sort of timer which when the user clicks on a certain page it trigger the counter, then with ngOnDestory when he leaves the page, stop the counter and send it to the backend to store it in the DB.

If anyone can give any advice on the easiest way to do so please let me know. I have read things such as `TimeMe.js` which is great but not sure how to implement it using Angular. Also seen the Window Event Handlers on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload.

It does **NOT** matter if the user is inactive or not looking at the page, that could be resolved after, first I need the timer just to get some research going.

Many thanks for you're time.

Comment: You can note a timestamp using Date.now() in ngOnInit and then again note timestamp in ngOnDestroy() and send difference of both to backend

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea, I will try to do the maths for it and post the answer. If you wish to gain the credit for your good answer, please create an answer so other users can benefit from this too, thank you @AbhaySehgal

Comment: Since scripts stop running in a timely manner if the user is not viewing the tab, I would advice to actually store the timestamps for opening the page and closing the page and calculating the difference server side. That way you get the actual time the page was open. If you'd use a timeout or an interval to count seconds like a clock, you'd notice that you only get the time viewing the page, not including the idle time spent on other tabs. So I would send to DB both on open and close instead of only on close.

Comment: Very good point @Shilly, once again same as Abhay above if you want to explain this with a little example, please post it in the answer section to help other users in case they ever come across this, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save timestamp using in ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy like

```
ngOnInit (){
    this.startTime = Date.now();
}
ngOnDestroy (){
    this.endTime = Date.now();
    totalTime = this.endTime - this.startTime;
}
```

Then totalTime will be the time you can send to backend

Answer (score 0):

You can save full timestamp in time format using in ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy

```html
   startTime: any = "";
  endTime: any = ""; 
  
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.startTime = new Date().getTime(); 
    }
  
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.endTime = new Date().getTime();
      this.appService.userTimeSpend(this.startTime,this.endTime)
    }
```

```html
userTimeSpend(start:any,end:any){
        const seconds= Math.round(Math.abs((start - end)/1000)); 
        const minutes = Math.floor(Math.abs((start - end)/60000)); 
          const hours = Math.floor(Math.abs((start - end) / 3600000));    
        let totalTime = (seconds >= 3600 ? hours + " hours  ":"")+(seconds >= 60 ?   minutes - (hours * 60) + " minutes  ":"")
        + (seconds - (minutes * 60)) + " seconds";
        console.log(totalTime);
      }
```

Time format will be **1 hour 4 minutes 12 seconds**

Comment: Your snippet is not being processed correctly.

Comment: but this code is working correctly

Comment: I did not say your code is not correct. But you should either convert it to code-only without being a snippet or make your snippet work. Currently if you click on Run Code Snippet, then your code is shown as text.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm new here so I don't know later on I'll learn this. Thanks for your advice.